# MongoDB Atlas search: sort by "searchScore"

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas, nosql-aggregation, mongodb-atlas-search

I run the following aggregation pipeline and it works well:

```
[
  {
    $search: {
      text: {
        query: text,
        path: 'name',
        fuzzy: {
          maxEdits: 2,
          prefixLength: 0,
          maxExpansions: 256,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $limit: 10,
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      score: { $meta: 'searchScore' },
     },
  },
]
```

I can see that the score-field is present in my result and is correct. Now I want to sort the documents retrieved by the `$meta`-property `searchScore`. However, adding this step at the end of the pipeline:

```
{
  $sort: { score: { $meta: 'searchScore' }, _id: 1 },
}
```

Yields the following error:

```
MongoError: $meta sort by 'searchScore' metadata is not supported
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Atlas Search sorts by score by default.  Adding a separate $sort stage will cause all of your data to be materialized and slow down your performance considerably.  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/scoring/

Comment: Also this should help with performance https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/performance/#-sort-aggregation-stage-usage

Comment: My pipeline was more complicated IRL. I have a form in my UI where the search input is optional. And I need different sorting based on if the query contained a search stage or not. However, now I understand that I probably should divide these into two queries for performance that leverages the default sorting of the text search.

Your input was very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new field that contains the result of `$meta` before sorting (which you already do) and then sort on that field, so you new pipeline would be:

```
...

{
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      score: { $meta: 'searchScore' }, // you are already adding the field here.
     },
},
{
   $sort: {
      score: -1, // use the new computed field here.
      _id: 1
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is this necessary? It's sorted by `searchScore` by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just directly perform the sort within the `$search` stage. Something like...

```
...
{
  $search: {
    text: {
      query: text,
      path: 'name',
      fuzzy: {
        maxEdits: 2,
        prefixLength: 0,
        maxExpansions: 256,
      },
    },
    sort: {score: {$meta: "searchScore", order: 1}}
  },
},
...
```

Reference: [Sort by Score Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/sort/#sort-by-score)

***Off Topic Note**: It's also worth considering that most of the time sorting should happen first before applying a limit in you query. That way you can have a consistent result, most especially if you're doing some pagination.*